# Dataverse Table creating multiple columns

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

Is there a faster way to create dataverse table columns instead of one by one?  I have a list of columns that I want to add and know what types I would like to assign to them.

Can I bulk update this easier or do I have to manually create each new column?

I've searched online and tried to find multiple solutions, but was not able to find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create or update Dataverse columns in bulk you can try with the XrmToolBox tool called Attributes Factory:

https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Javista.AttributesFactory/

you can install it directly from the Tool Library inside XrmToolBox

Comment: Yes, this looks like the solution I need.  However, I am not able to create additional columns as I keep getting an "Object Reference not set to instance" error when the column doesn't exist.  Existing columns seem to get updated though.

Comment: There was a bug and it has been corrected